# How to highlight text in pdf in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, pdf, highlighting

I want to search text in pdf and want to highlight it but don't know how to do that.
Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, PDFKit is not available for iPhone; therefore, you should resort to manipulating the PDF through Quartz directly. You can refer to the [QuartzDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Introduction/Intro.html), which also covers a bit of PDF manipulation, for an example of that.